# Best way to set handler for checkbox element, that was created with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox

I have on my web-page 5000 cards. Each card contains a checkbox. All of the cards and the checkbox were created with jQuery when the webpage was loaded.

'''

```
  function createTitleAndToggleButtonInContainer(titleAndToggleContainer, coinData) {

    $("<h5></h5>", {
        "class": "card-title",
        text: coinData.id
    }).appendTo(titleAndToggleContainer);


    let toggleContainer = $("<div></div>", {
        "class": "switch"
    });

    let input = $("<input>", {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "name": "toggle",
    

    }).appendTo(toggleContainer);
```

'''

This piece of code is called 5000 times. I want to add an event handler for the checkbox.
If the user checks more than 5 checkboxes - a modal window will display with the IDs of the cards. I will have a global counter and each time a checkbox will be checked the counter ++.

I need a way to know which checkbox was checked because I need to know the ID of the cards it came from. What is the best way to set an event handling with jQuery to the checkbox and the most important is how to have the ability to know which checkbox was clicked

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: have you tried `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log($(this).attr("name"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var idCnt =0;
var coinData={id:'supercut'}
var titleAndToggleContainer = document.getElementById("titleAndToggleContainer");


function createTitleAndToggleButtonInContainer(titleAndToggleContainer, coinData) {    
    $("<h5></h5>", {
        "class": "card-title",
        "text": coinData.id +idCnt
    }).appendTo(titleAndToggleContainer);


    let toggleContainer = $("<div></div>", {
        "class": "switch"
    }).appendTo(titleAndToggleContainer);    

    let input = $("<input>", {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "name": "toggle",
        "onchange":"countChecks()",
    }).appendTo(toggleContainer);  
    
}
    
    
    
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    idCnt++;
    
    createTitleAndToggleButtonInContainer(titleAndToggleContainer, coinData) ;
    }
    
    
    
    function countChecks(){
    var whichOnes=[];
    var cnt = 0;
    var checks = document.getElementsByName('toggle')
    for(let i = 0;i<checks.length;i++){
    
    
    
    
     if (checks[i].checked){
     
     whichOnes.push(cnt);
     }
     
     cnt++;
     
     
     
    }
    if(whichOnes.length>=5)alert('down the rabbit hole');
    console.log(whichOnes)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='titleAndToggleContainer'></div>
```